# Describing RESTful URLs

Tags: http, rest, url, terminology, restful-url

Here's an example URL:

```
/users/123/comments
```

Based on this URL, which term would best describe `users`? Is `users` the resource or is it a part of the resource. What would be the name of that part?

The same question goes for the other parts. Which terms would best describe `123` and `comments`?

Is there a term that would refer to the second part of RESTful URLs? It would describe `123` in `/users/123` and `purchases` in `/me/purchases`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST is a Resource-Oriented. URLs represent resources.

In your example, `/users/123/comments`:

- `users` is a resource.
- `123` is the unique identifier of an user.
- In this case, comments are a sub-resource of users, but they are probably resources on their own *(ex. calling `/comments/{id}`)*

About your second question, the format for `/me/purchases` is not the same as `/users/123`. And `/me/purchases` is probably a short URL for something like `/users/{myid}/purchases` where `purchases` are a sub-resource of users *(and probably a resource on their own also, available by `/purchases/{id}`)*.

---

*For more information, [here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=NEWTPFzt2-E), that is not directly related to your question, but that is very well made and very interesting about REST web services.*

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `http://example.org/users/123/comments` points to a resource.  A complete URI is an identifier for a resource.

Let me give you an extreme example,

`/users/123/comments.xml`

`/users/123/comments.json`

are two different resources.

The query string also identifies resources, so

`/users/123/comments?format=xml`

`/users/123/comments?format=json`

are also two different resources.

**Resources do not map to entities**.  Resources are "some concept" that you wish to expose over HTTP and have identified with a URI.

In RESTful system URIs are opaque to the system design.  A client of your system should not try and infer meaning from portions of your URI.  A server can setup conventions to help it build a URI space, but these are private implementation details of the server.

There is **no such thing as a RESTFul url**.  The term is a fabrication of framework designers and will just serve to confuse you.

Comment: I don't agree that `format=xml`, `format=json`, `format=html` points to different resources. They point to the same resource, but to different representations of that resource. I might be wrong, but this is what I've seen before

Comment: @HugoDozois Here http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/11147 is a post from Roy Fielding from 2008 where he describes two URIs that only differ by "extension" as "format-specific **resources**"